# Как прописать в коде использование мобильной сети для передачи по ней?

Tags: java, android, сокет

Написал приложение для Android которое предаёт фотографии на сервер, но вот в чём проблема по ***wi-fi в локальной сети приложение работает***, а вот если я отключаю wi-fi и перехожу на ***мобильный интернет*** 4g, то ничего с него не приходит таблицы проброса на роутере прописал.

```
 protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            GlobalIpServer  = InetAddress.getByName(inetadress);
            System.out.println("ip адрес домена ipMainServer на данный момент: "+ GlobalIpServer.getHostAddress());
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            if (GlobalIpServer != null) {
                //----------------------------------------------
                client = new Socket(GlobalIpServer, portMainServer);
                //----------------------------------------------
        }
    }
```

Comment: А какое отношение имеют "таблицы проброса на роутере" к мобильному интернету? Вы хотите через глобальную сеть достучаться до сервера на своём ПК что-ли? Поподробнее немножко опишите ситуацию.

Comment: @woesss Всё верно или есть другой вариант если  wi-fi не доступен будет, а только мобильная сеть?

Comment: Да варианты-то есть, но пока не понятно что и для чего вы делаете. Локальная и глобальная сеть это две большие разницы и размещать сервер у себя на домашнем ПК для юзания его кем попало - это сомнительная затея.

Comment: @woesss моя затея пересылать себе на сервер фото своим собственным приложением.

Comment: @woesss буду очень благодарен если поясните, что приведённый мной код должен так же работать и с мобильной сетью или ещё что то нужно дописать?

Comment: На клиентской стороне принципиальной разницы нет через какую сеть работать. Единственное что приходит на ум - в локальной сети ПК виден под локальным ip, выданным роутером, а в глобальной сети нужно стучаться на внешний адрес, выданный провайдером. Для глобального доступа к ПК нужен статический ip, либо промежуточный сервис, либо каким-то другим образом выяснять текущий внешний ip. Научить роутер адресовать запросы к серверу на ПК. Настроить всякие сетевые экраны и сам сервер. Не проще кидать фото через любой мессенджер/почту, когда сервер недоступен локально?

Comment: Ваш вопрос по сути не имеет отношения к разработке приложений на Андроид, это чисто админская задача настроить доступ извне на внутрисетевой ресурс.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что не имеет отношения к разработке приложений на Андроид

Comment: @woesss не проще, зачем тогда я его писал) Спасибо если для передачи по мобильной сети мой представленный код подходит тогда вы ответили на мой вопрос. Поставьте в ответ.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja не совсем с вами согласен я для того и спрашивал что бы это выяснить так как подозревал, что для передачи по мобильной сети нужно что то ещё дописать.